# Time limit in Prolog user input (read)

Tags: time, prolog, limit, interpreter

I'm writing an interpreter for a game. User enters its move to the interpreter and program executes that move.

Now I want to implement a time limit for each decision. Player shouldn't be able to think more than 30 seconds to write a move and press enter.

call_with_time_limit seemed relevant but it doesnt work properly as such:

call_with_time_limit( 30, read(X) ), Problem, write(Problem).

In this case, it waits for input, and when input is entered, timer starts afterwards. But I want the timer to start at the beginning.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please look at my answer for `read/1`!

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in I/O related timeouts please consider [`wait_for_input/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=wait_for_input/3) or `set_stream/2`. The built-in you found, `call_with_time_limit/2` is not a simple and reliable interface.

Edit: I just see that you use `read/1` for input.  Please read in above documentation how to avoid blocking in `read/1`.  It is not clear to me why you need this, but a user might simply enter <kbd>Return</kbd>, thereby circumventing the initial timeout.  `read/1` would now read that `'\n'` but then would wait for further input - without a timeout, while the user lavishly skims Wikipedia for the answer... might even ask the question on SO...

Comment: The interesting part to look at is in `interpret(Move)`.  I mean, `Move` is a list of inputs ready to read... So the name `Move` is not ideal to say the least...

Comment: Should I say inputs? Then I should parse the list like [command | parameter]?

Comment: (not easy if you delete what we are referring to) If its the `user_input`, you already know the name. And it is never as you say [command|parameter]  It is either `[user_input]` or `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems sensible: from the SWI-Prolog docs: 'Blocking I/O can be handled using the timeout option of read_term/3. '.

That's not really informative: changing timeout on user leads to some bug (I'll test more and will report to SWI_prolog mailing list if appropriate), even under catch/3.

The following seems to work

```
...,
current_input(I),
wait_for_input([I], A, 30),
...
```

If not input given (shorter time to test here...)

```
?- current_input(I), wait_for_input([I],A,5).
I = <stream>(0x7fa75bb31880),
A = [].
```

**EDIT**: the variable A will keep the list will contain the list of streams with ready input: I just reported the case where the user doesn't input anything before the timeout occurs. To get the actual input, using your supplied code:

```
tql :-
    current_player(I),
    writef('Its %d. players turn: ', [I]),
    flush_output,
    current_input(Input),
    wait_for_input([Input], [Input], 5),
    read(Input, Move),
    writeln(Move).

current_player(1).
```

HTH

Comment: current_player(I),
    writef('Its %d. players turn: ', [I]),
    current_input(Input),
    wait_for_input([Input], Move, 5),
    interpret(Move),

Its 1. players turn: 
ERROR: wait_for_input/3: stream `[<stream>(100ECB58)]' does not exist (Invalid argument)